# How do I add another attribute to order_aggregated_created table?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I’ve been scratching my head for days on this one. Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I’ve extended the sales report under Reports->Sales->Orders and created my own custom filters to filer the report by channels. 
Each order has a ‘channel_name’ attribute to identify whether the order came from eBay, Amazon, etc.

Now I cannot for the life of me figure out how sales/order_aggregated_created table that is used to generate the reports is created. Where does the magic happen? I want to add ‘channel_name’ to the order_aggregated_created table to be able to filter by this attribute, but I cannot figure out how to this.

Diagram for order_aggregated_created table with its attributes: 
http://www.magento-exchange.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/MAGENTO-SALES-ORDER-ER.png

Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Collection is where the magic starts in retrieving the sales totals, particularly if I understood this correctly inside

```
protected function _getSelectedColumns(){...}

        if (!$this->isTotals()) {
            $this->_selectedColumns = array(
                'period'                         => $this->_periodFormat,
                'orders_count'                   => 'SUM(orders_count)',
                'total_qty_ordered'              => 'SUM(total_qty_ordered)',
                'total_qty_invoiced'             => 'SUM(total_qty_invoiced)',
                'total_income_amount'            => 'SUM(total_income_amount)',
                'total_revenue_amount'           => 'SUM(total_revenue_amount)',
                'total_profit_amount'            => 'SUM(total_profit_amount)',
                'total_invoiced_amount'          => 'SUM(total_invoiced_amount)',
                'total_canceled_amount'          => 'SUM(total_canceled_amount)',
                'total_paid_amount'              => 'SUM(total_paid_amount)',
                'total_refunded_amount'          => 'SUM(total_refunded_amount)',
                'total_tax_amount'               => 'SUM(total_tax_amount)',
                'total_tax_amount_actual'        => 'SUM(total_tax_amount_actual)',
                'total_shipping_amount'          => 'SUM(total_shipping_amount)',
                'total_shipping_amount_actual'   => 'SUM(total_shipping_amount_actual)',
                'total_discount_amount'          => 'SUM(total_discount_amount)',
                'total_discount_amount_actual'   => 'SUM(total_discount_amount_actual)',
            );
        }
```

If would be awesome if I can just ‘channel_name’ =>$this->_channelName, and be on my merry way.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot and lot of research it turns out that sales/order_aggregated_created table gets generated in here:

Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat

now I've looked here before seemed like exactly what I needed, but any changes I made would not reflect in Magento reports especially inside the sales/order_aggregated_created table.

I found out that Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat only gets called when you refresh the statistics inside Reports->Sales->Orders, only then a NEW sales/order_aggregated_created table is generated! So for anyone looking to filter the order sales report by a custom attribute, look inside: /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createat.php